# Не знаю как решить задачу с массивами на Python

Tags: python, массивы

[image: Тз Задания]

Парни, есть такая задача. Помогите пожалуйста со 2 вариантом ( первый я уже скинул в ответах)

Comment: Массив, конечно, можно создать. Но это не требуется для решения задачи ) Например, целочисленное деление позиции на 120 даст номер яруса. Секцию можно определить таким же способом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Секцию можно найти по аналогии, ярус - банально по последней цифре )

```
import math


def searh_product(position: str) -> tuple:
    sek = math.ceil(int(position) / 150)
    last = int(position[-1])
    yar = last if last != 0 else 10
    return sek, yar


while 1:
    number = input("Введите номер места: ")
    if not number.isdigit():
        print("Введите число")
    elif int(number) > 1200:
        print("Места нет на складе")
    else:
        sekcia, yarus = searh_product(number)
        print("Секция - {}, Ярус - {}".format(sekcia, yarus))
```

Answer (score 0):

Впринципе, первый вариант решил без создания массива, таким способом

```
import math
# Первый вариант задачи

number = int(input("Введите номер места: "))

yarus = math.ceil(number / 120)
print("Номер яруса: " + str(yarus))
number -= 1
sekcia = math.ceil((number % 120 + 1) / 15)
print("Номер секции: " + str(sekcia))
# Второй вариант задачи

sekcia = math.ceil(number / 150)
print("Номер секции: " + str(sekcia))
number -= 1
yarus = number % 10 + 1
print("Номер яруса: " + str(yarus))
```